# F# Type Provider Dependent Nested Types

Tags: f#, type-providers, dependent-type, f#-data

I am trying to build a TypeProvider where nested `ProvidedProperty` is generated based on parent's type value.

A result I want to have is following

```
#r @"bin/Debug/library.dll"
open Library.TypeProviders

type sdmx = SdmxDataProvider<WsEntryPoint="">
let dataflows = sdmx.GetDataFlowsContext()

let a = dataflows.A.A1 // A1,A2,A3 < should be generated based on A
let b = dataflows.B.B1 // B1,B2,B3 < should be generated based on B
let c = dataflows.C.C1 // C1,C2,C3 < should be generated based on C
```

I could generate all `dimensionsType`s for all `dataflowsType`s.

[image]

Then I tried to add argument `dfId` and then use it to choose properties.

```
let dimensionsType dfId =
    let t = ProvidedTypeDefinition("Dimensions", Some typeof<string>)
    t.AddMembersDelayed (fun () -> 
        [ for dimension in [(1, "A1"); (1, "A2"); (1, "A3");
                            (2, "B1"); (2, "B2"); (2, "B3");
                            (3, "C1"); (3, "C2"); (3, "C3")] do
              let dataflowId, dimensionName = dimension
              if dataflowId = dfId then
                  let prop = 
                      ProvidedProperty
                        ( dimensionName, typeof<string>, 
                          GetterCode = (fun args -> <@@ (%%args.[0]) :> string @@>))
                  yield prop                     
        ])
    serviceTypesType.AddMember t
    t

let dataflowsType =
    let t = ProvidedTypeDefinition("Dataflows", Some typeof<string>)
    t.AddMembersDelayed (fun () ->
        [ for dataflow in [(1, "A"); (2, "B") ; (3, "C")] do
            let dataflowId, dataflowName = dataflow
            let prop = ProvidedProperty(dataflowName, dimensionsType dataflowId, GetterCode = (fun args -> <@@ (%%args.[0]) :> string @@>))
            yield prop])
    serviceTypesType.AddMember t
    t
```

This approach raises error: `error FS1109: A reference to the type 'Library.TypeProviders.SdmxDataProvider,WsEntryPoint="".ServiceTypes.Dimensions' in assembly 'Library' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly`

Is it possible to do this kind of type generation?

Full Source: https://gist.github.com/demonno/f9234ced664439986597cf7c3218d3b8

Comment: What problems are you having? What are you trying to do that does not work?

Comment: The only idea I had and tried is to add an argument to `dimensionsType` and then simply check by if statement (snippet updated). The build is successful but getting following error on executing `dataflows.A`.  `error FS1109: A reference to the type 'Library.TypeProviders.SdmxDataProvider,WsEntryPoint="".ServiceTypes.Dimensions' in assembly 'Library' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly`

Comment: @TomasPetricek: An attempt to summarize demonnos problem: he wants to create an SDMX type provider. In SDMX each dataflow has dimensions, all of which need to be instantiated before we can actually access the data. He wants to constrain the options for each dimension to only types generated from that particular dimension values. He wants to use these selections as parameters to the type provider providing actual data, so the attempt is to arrive at some sort of dependent types approach where the dimension selections parameterize the data provider at type level.